# <lightning:input variant="label-hidden"> input does not take whole parent width

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

when I use :

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <div>
        <lightning:input type="text" label="myLabel" name="withLabel" value="withLabel" />
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

The input element takes the whole width of the parent element (and that's excellent):

[image]

But when I use the `label-hidden` option:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <div>
        <lightning:input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="noLabel" name="noLabel" value="noLabel" />
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

The input element takes only part of the parent element (and that is my problem):

[image]

I tried to play with css to fix that, but I couldn't find the right solution.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why is the component not taking 100% width when the label is hidden?
2. Is there a better way to define the `lightning:input` component so this behavior will be fixed?
3. If not - I need a good css solution to this problem.

**UPDATE - added css rules that did not work**

```
.THIS .lightningInput {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing what css rules you have tried along with scope?

Comment: @glls question updated

Comment: what about the parent, could you include the parent node for reference purposes?

Comment: @glls - added the whole code

Comment: Check out the [Summer '18 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_styles.htm) about an important change as this might have been addressed by the system no longer applying the `slds-form_inline` styling. To maintain hidden labels without the label still taking up space on the page, see my answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/221202/987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- the SLDS styling changes the form element scoping when using the variant label-hidden.

2.- you can specify the width of your element in your styling yourself.

3.- you can add a class to your lightning:input component, and use child selector in order to expand the input element to 100% width:

component.cmp

```
<lightning:input class="child"..../>
```

component.css

```
.THIS .child>.slds-form-element__control {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @glls - I have tried your solution, problem is, when I set a width like that suddenly the hidden label also takes it's height. As I see it - this is a bug with the `variant="label-hidden"` attribute, and the easiest way is not to use this attribute and hide the label with css with `display: none`

Comment: If you scope your css properly you can fix the height issue, about it being a bug, have you contacted support?

Comment: I do not have access to this kind of support. It looks like a bug to me, don't you think so?

Comment: I am marking this answer as the accepted answer, although my better solution was to not use `variant="label-hidden"`, and hide the label with css

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the label completely, you can put the display to none for that label by accessing `.slds-form-element__label` class.

App Markup

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <div>
        <lightning:input type="text" label="MyLabel1" name="withoutLabel" value="withoutLabel" class="nolabel" />
        <lightning:input type="text" label="MyLabel2" name="withLabel" value="withLabel" />
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

CSS

```
.THIS .nolabel .slds-form-element__label{
    display: none; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

*Note: This is not recommended as you are using the framework level CSS and likely to be fragile.*