# Summer 18 - Lightning input variant label-hidden hides the label but occupies the space for label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, summer-18

I am trying to include lightning:select component in a table row. But I don't want to show the label for select input. I am using variant="label-hidden", which hides the label, but the space for the label is still occupied. As a result, the select input moves down and is not aligned with rest of the column values in a row.

I noticed this issue as soon as our org was updated to Summer 18. Please let me know if there is a fix for this other than overriding the CSS for the label.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The label no longer being hidden is impacted by the Summer '18 change where many base lightning components no longer automatically include the `slds-form_inline` or `slds-form--inline` CSS class.

Per the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_styles.htm):

> The slds-form_inline (formerly slds-form--inline) style was removed. When applied, the style made the element’s width unchangeable.
>
> **Where**: This change affects Lightning components that support the `label-hidden` variant: `lightning:input`, `lightning:combobox`, `lightning:dualListbox`, `lightning:radioGroup`, `lightning:select`, and `lightning:textarea`. The style is no longer applied when you use the `label-hidden` variant, but you shouldn’t notice a difference in the rendering of the components in most cases.
>
> **Why**: The slds-form_inline style was mistakenly applied by the label-hidden variant.

I'm not sure what scenarios the statement "you shouldn’t notice a difference in the rendering of the components in most cases." refers to, but when using **variant: label-hidden** this change has visible differences compared to earlier versions of Salesforce.

## Workarounds

### Option 1. (recommended) Add custom component styling

I recommend this option as you avoid any of the negative side effects for why Salesforce removed usage of the `slds-form_line` class but you get the benefit of hiding the label, which is the desired effect.

Assign a custom class to your input component (I chose to name my class 'label-hidden' after the variant) and then add styling for it in your component's style resource.

*YourComponent.cmp*

```
<lightning:select
    label="Select Account"
    variant="label-hidden"
    class="label-hidden"
    value="{!v.selectedAccountId}">
    ...
</lightning:select>
```

*YourComponent.css*

```
.THIS .label-hidden > label {
    display: none;
}
```

### Option 2. Add back the class `slds-form_line` to your component

This approach tries to reproduce the original behavior pre Summer '18, but you maintain any of the negative reasons why Salesforce decided to remove its usage. However, you don't have to create a custom style resource for your component.

*YourComponent.cmp*

```
<lightning:select
    label="Select Account"
    variant="label-hidden"
    class="slds-form_inline"
    value="{!v.selectedAccountId}">
    ...
</lightning:select>
```

Comment: Thank you Doug. We have decided to move forward with Option 2 and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: We still observe problem with Lightning:select and second option doesn't work for us, only the first option work.

Answer (score 9):

Update: As of Winter '19, using Lightning:input variant="label-hidden" works again as the author had hoped (there is no space occupied by the would-be label).

Sample markup:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-text-heading_medium slds-has-flexi-truncate">Page Title</div>
    <lightning:input class="slds-col slds-float_right slds-has-flexi-truncate" type="search" variant="label-hidden" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: works for lightning:input but not for lightning:select

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue with input as well. The css definitions are improved in Summer'18. In our case replacing `.slds-input.slds-is-disabled` with `.slds-input[disabled]` fixed the problem. My suggestion would be to take a look at the CSS definition changes.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a bold label and had to do all sorts to get the right style...

```
.THIS .label-hidden > label {
   display: none;
}

.THIS .addmargin {
   padding: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.THIS .thick {
   font-weight: bold;}
}
```

And the component:

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="horizontal-small" > 
   <label class="thick " for="taskCatType">Type:</label>
   <lightning:select  aura:id="taskCatType" value="{!v.singleRec.CCMI__Type__c}"  class="label-hidden addmargin" onchange="{!c.onFieldChange}"  disabled="{!v.singleRec.CCMI__Status__c == 'Completed'}">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.catPicklistOpts}" var="typeopt">
         <option text="{!typeopt.label}"  value = "{!typeopt.value}" ></option>
      </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
 </lightning:layoutItem>
```