# Uncaught Assertion Failed - label attribute required

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-18

I've got this error while Lightning Component debug mode is enabled:

```
Uncaught Assertion Failed!: <lightning-input> The required label attribute value "undefined" is invalid. : false
Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getComponent
```

The component itself is really simple:

CMP:

```
<aura:component access="global">
<aura:attribute name="TargetName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="TargetDescription" type="String"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="stepOneEvent" type="c:TargetProcessStepOneEvent"/>

<lightning:progressIndicator class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium" currentStep="step1" type="base" variant="base">
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 1" value="step1"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 2" value="step2"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 3" value="step3"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 4" value="step4"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 5" value="step5"></lightning:progressStep>
</lightning:progressIndicator>  

<div class="slds-m-right_xx-large slds-m-left_xx-large" style="font-size: 0.8125rem;"><b>1) First, name your Target</b></div>
    <div class="slds-m-left_xx-large slds-p-left_xx-large" style="font-size: 0.625rem;">Give your target a friendly name so others will identify target purpose quickly</div>
    <lightning:layout class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning:layoutItem >
           <lightning:input aura:id="field" name="targetName" value="{!v.TargetName}" required="true" placeholder="Enter Target Name" class="slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>        
    </lightning:layout>

    <div class="slds-m-right_xx-large slds-m-left_xx-large" style="font-size: 0.8125rem;"><b>2) Describe your Target</b></div>
    <div class="slds-m-left_xx-large slds-p-left_xx-large" style="font-size: 0.625rem;">Describe what this Target will be monitoring and how it should be working</div>
    <lightning:layout class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning:layoutItem >
            <lightning:input aura:id="field" name="Description__c" value="{!v.TargetDescription}" required="true" placeholder="Enter description" class="slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>        
    </lightning:layout>

<!-- BUTTONS -->
<lightning:layout class="slds-p-top_medium slds-p-bottom_medium">
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">
            <lightning:button class="slds-theme_neutral" iconPosition="left" variant="neutral" type="button" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelDialog}"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">
            <lightning:button class="slds-theme_inverse slds-align_absolute-center" iconPosition="left" variant="inverse" type="button" label="Next" onclick="{!c.fireEvent}"/>
            <!-- style="float:right" -->
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
    cancelDialog : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        action.fire();
    },

    fireEvent : function(component,event,helper){

    var allValid = component.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);

        if (allValid) {
            var name = component.get("{!v.TargetName}");
            var description = component.get("{!v.TargetDescription}");
            var myEvent = component.getEvent("stepOneEvent");
            myEvent.setParams({"targetName" : name, "targetDescription" : description});
            myEvent.fire();
        }
    }
})
```

Component works fine with debug mode disabled. Also I started to experience this after my org has switched into Summer 18' Release. Any clue on this error?

Comment: The `label` field for lightning input is required. If you want to hide it in you can use `variant` as `label-hidden`. I am not sure why is it error-ing out in debug mode(maybe strict checking). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification

Comment: According to this topic https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220616/summer-18-lightning-input-variant-label-hidden-hides-the-label-but-occupies-th/221202#221202 , your solution is no more valid unfortunately.