# How do I remove the gap between a label and a lightning:select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, label, lightningselect

In order to have a bold label, I separated it and hid the label on the select element.
However, it seems to leave the label space. (This doesn't happen with lightning:input elements).

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="horizontal-small" > 
                 
                    <label class="thick" for="taskCatType">Type:</label>
                     <lightning:select  aura:id="taskCatType" value="{!v.singleRec.CCMI__Type__c}"  variant="label-hidden"
                                  onchange="{!c.onFieldChange}"  disabled="{!v.singleRec.CCMI__Status__c == 'Completed'}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.catPicklistOpts}" var="typeopt">
                        <option text="{!typeopt.label}"  value = "{!typeopt.value}" ></option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                              </lightning:layoutItem>
```

[image]

Comment: Found a clue at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220616/summer-18-lightning-input-variant-label-hidden-hides-the-label-but-occupies-th/408519#408519 which led me to a solution.