# Lightning:textarea is half the width of 2-of-12 of slds-grid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-textarea

I've got this sorta table with lightning:textarea component that severely limited itself in width.

Not sure why this happens.[image]

Comment: Half space seems to be taken by the label element. Share some code for us to try and help further?

Comment: @Raul not really - it's the `slds-form-element__control`. But I don't know what to take from it.

Comment: Also, in this case there is no label (`variant="label-hidden"`)

Comment: There is a problem while using the `variant="label-hidden"` attribute - I have encountered it using `lightning:input` - I did not find any solution, but what you are describing here looks like the same: [<lightning:input variant=“label-hidden”> input does not take whole parent width](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216459/lightninginput-variant-label-hidden-input-does-not-take-whole-parent-width)

Comment: It seems that there was a change in Summer 18 release that fixed this. Sorry for not adding more info on this, will do soon once I get back to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, given you have placed the text area within a column size 2-12.

I would recommend you check slds's [Sizing utilities](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/)

[image]

maybe consider changing the column size of your component's child column elements.

other things to check:

- padding
- margins

Additionally, sharing your code might help us better help you.